# Facebook appending fbclid with outbound links and web page showing 'ERR_CONNECTION_RESET'

Tags: asp.net, linux, facebook, nginx, iis

I am facing this issue on `linux` and `windows` both.

I've a simple web application template with only one html page named `index.html` I've deployed it to `linux` and `windows` hosting.

Similarly, I've created a `facebook` page and I posted a link of my website.

When I click on link `facebook` opens up a new window and it's like `wwww.foo.com/?fbclid=XXXXXXXXXXXX` and web page does not load rather `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` appears.

I've tried few solutions but nothing worked.

**Linux Ubuntu**

I checked the `ningx` `access.log` and when I click on outbound Url in facebook and it comes to my web pages following line appears in `nginx access.log`

```
[21/Jul/2020:13:10:05 +0500] "HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily" 400 182 "-" "-"
```

I've tried following block but it does nothing.

```
location / {

           error_page 302 =301 http://example.com/notfound.html;
 }
```

When an outbound link open up a web page its URL is like:

```
foo.com/index.html?fbclid=IwAR1RoE_FBHre-gTMc3IzkycdYHskuUBlVi4HfKQjuiBN0N4uryxWrKAcDpo
```

It appears with `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. If I will refresh the page manually it will show page but not from facebook post URL.

**Window Server**

**Solution#1**

In `Web.config` I've tried rule which is as follow:

```
<system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="SpecificRedirectFBClid" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^fbclid=" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="foo.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
```

**Solution#2**

I've also tried adding

```
<link rel="canonical" href="foo.com">   
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="CACHE">
```

My end goal is to load website. It does not matter either `fbclid` appears in query parameter or not.

When I click on my website link in facebook post it opens up it in a new window with error. But when I refresh page in the same window it load smoothly.

I've read multiple forums and blogs but could not get anything for ASP.NET Web application.

**FINAL SOLUTION**

I got the solution. My application was running on **http** and once I changed http to https everything started working. I think at my server I had SSL certificate which was not configured. I am not sure what was the cause. But once I changed http to https everything worked as expected.

Comment: Is your application behind a load balancer points to multiple instances running this app?